# Suggestion Required for the mobile app release

Tags: android, ios, mobile, frontend

Apologies for asking a very basic question, as I am new to mobile app development.

Our team has an application live for customers on iOS and Android. We are working on revamping the application for customers. We want to evaluate an option to release the new update for customers who don't have the app installed on their phones. For the customers who have the application installed, we don't want to provide an update.

Is that possible?

Comment: No.  When you release a new version your old version is no longer available, unless you release it as a completely new app, but then when you do want your existing customers to update they will need to uninstall the old app and install the new one from the stores.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs @Paulw11. If we launch a completely new app with the same apple account is that possible that the existing customer doesn't see the new app and meanwhile we launch the new app for customers who hasn't installed the old app

Comment: No, existing customers would see the new app because it is an unrelated app in the App Stores. You would also have to remove the old app from sale to prevent new users from seeing that.  That would also mean that you could never issue any updates to that old app.  In general, it sounds like a bad plan.

Comment: Got it thanks it was just a thought but wanted community feedback.